# Generate int constant for each file in raw directory

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

My problem is that to play a sound for the notification, you need a URI, which is easy to get. I have 153 files that are loaded in though, so I used an enhanced for loop to load each one in instead of doing in individually. This is how I did it:

```
SoundPool pool = getSoundPool();
File raw = context.getDir("raw", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
for(File file : raw.listFiles()){
    pool.load(file.getPath(), 0);
}
```

By the way, I have not yet tested this. If it is wrong, then correct me please.

Back on topic, the URIs need the R.raw.name thing for each .playSound call. Having stored each sound as a file, I don't have the int constant for each one.

My question: Is there an easy way to generate the int constant for a random file in the directory, which I could then use to generate a URI? I don't want to go through all 153 sounds and define the constant for each one.

Answer (score 0):

keep the name of all the files in raw folder to something common suffixed with an integer. lets say the name you choose is `rawname`

your file names then are rawname1, rawname2, rawname2 ...

then write a loop and use the loop index and get the resource by its name using this:

```
for(int i=1; i<=153; i++) {
    int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("rawname" + Integer.toString(i), "raw", this.getPackageName());
}
```

You can then use `drawableResourceId` where you need to put your `R.raw.name`.